# How to create the session and set the UserBean in session

Tags: c#, nancy

I am new to Nancy and .NET framework. here I am running in a panic situation.

I have written my own `Bootstrapper` to enable `CookieBasedSessions` in project.Here are tasks i have to perform.

1. Once user logged in create session and set `User` in session.
2. Then on each request verify the user in `session`

   ```
    class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
   {
   protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
   {
       base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
       CookieBasedSessions.Enable(pipelines);
   }

   }
   ```

Here is my controller.

```
     Post["/myapp/login"] = parameters =>
        {
            var model = new User();
            model.UserName = this.Request.Form.userName;


            model = manager.GetUser(model.UserName);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName) && model.isAdmin())
            {
               // var user = Request.Session["user"];
                if (Request.Session["key"] != null)  // Here i get the ERROR
                    Request.Session["key"] = model;

                return Response.AsRedirect(HOME_URL);
            }
            else
                return Response.AsRedirect(LOGIN_URL);
        };
```

when I execute this code I am getting `{"Session support is not enabled."}` error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not using your custom bootstrapper - make the class public and it will pick it up.

Comment: thanks for your reply it solved the problem. Can you please tell me how to get/set the values in session.

Comment: Just using Session["key"], there's a sample route in the main asp.net demo project https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Aspnet/MainModule.cs#L129

Comment: Link is now https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/samples/Nancy.Demo.Hosting.Aspnet/MainModule.cs if anyone cares